# Best Free Direction Field Plotter?

Tags: software, vector-calculus, calculators

Can you recommend one for a first or second year calculus course?

Ideally the website that can plot direction fields:

- is free
- is 100% WYSIWYG (does not require any coding or markup or anything of the sort)
- does not require payment, login, download, etc.
- can plot a solution curve given a point
- can plot slopes of varying density on the plane

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found a good example on Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jkjgxemmkj

And another on Geogebra: https://www.geogebra.org/m/W7dAdgqc